# Spring MVC - Cannot create file at webapp/resources/

Tags: java, spring, file

I want to create file at 'webapp/resources/'

I used following code.

```
String filepath = "classpath:webapp/resources/" + filename +".json";
File file = new File(filepath);

if (!file.exists()) {

            file.createNewFile();
}
```

but error occured.

ex) no such file or directory

I think file path is incorrect.

I don't know real path of '/webapp/resources/'.

Comment: Use servlet context of response to get the real path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to get **Physical Path** from Servlet Context like

```
   //add HttpServletRequest request in spring controller as parameter
   String phyPath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");

   String filepath = phyPath + "resources/" + filename +".json";
   File file = new File(filepath);
   if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
   }
```

Be carefull before using it because after project re-deloyed,it will be flushed.
  Other better option is to create **CDN(Content Delivery Network) like server** and store file there.

Comment: this is what my physical path looks like 
C:\Users\Dell\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.4.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\IrApp\resources/but not uploading file there. any reason

Answer (score 1):

`java.io.File` knows nothing about `classpath:` prefix. It passes profided filepath directly to OS system function. And filepath is treated verbatim. So you get error because there is no file with path `classpath:webapp/resources/blah-blab.json`.

One of your options is to use [getRealPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String)). But this is not portable and depends on how your application is deployed and what application server is used. In some cases application deployed as war is not unpacked, it is also possible that application is unpacked to temporary folder which is cleared between application server reboot. In general this behavior is application server specific and should not be relied on.